# How to write an approve action in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

i want to create an simple application that will allow graduating students to register for graduation attendance. From the application form the student enter the details that's saved to the students table waiting for approval. The admin then approves the request and the record is inserted in the approved table and deleted from the students table. How can i write the approve action and how can i move the record to the approved table in cakephp 2.6.3.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use one and same table to save this data. Use the table students. Add a `approved` column to the table where 0 = not approved, 1 = approved. When students are entering their data and saves it to students table, make sure `approved = 0`. Then admin can go change this value to 1 if student is approved.

```
// StudentsController.php
public function approve($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Student->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->Student->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The student has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'notice success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The student could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'notice error'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Student.' . $this->Student->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Student->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

app/View/Students/approve.ctp:

```
<h1><?php echo __('Approve student');?></h1>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Student'); ?>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('approved', array('label' => __('Approve'), 'options' => array(
            '0' => __('Not approved'),
            '1' => __('Approved'),
        )));
    ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => __('Save'), 'class' => 'button')); ?>
```

Sorry for not answering your exact question, but I really think it is unnecessary to use two tables to identify who are not approved vs approved students.

Comment: sorry for replying late. your answer really gave me an idea of how to go about it and i managed to get the app working. Thank you Christian.